# How to make an own time table in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-layout, button

I'm setting up my own time table and I have a lot of button on that I want to get multi-button I mean if someone wants to use the application. they can choose any time they want to have no limit. so how can I make a time table with those options?

**here  its XML file:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="370dp"
android:layout_height="480dp"
android:background="#00555555"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp"
android:weightSum="100">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/round_layout_otp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="7dp"
    android:weightSum="100">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="166dp"
        android:layout_weight="60"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="80"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/a"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/logo" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_file_path"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="TEXTO"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="457dp"
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:background="@drawable/round_layout_white_otp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="100">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Chose Your Time :"
                android:textColor="#ff000000"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="769dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="60">

            <ScrollView android:id="@+id/layout"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TableRow
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="75dp">
                        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="8:00" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:textSize="13sp" android:id="@+id/bt1" android:background="@color/colorAccent" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
                        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="8:15" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:textSize="13sp" android:id="@+id/bt2" android:background="@color/colorAccent" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
                        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="8:30" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:textSize="13sp" android:id="@+id/bt3" android:background="@color/colorAccent" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
                        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="8:45" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:textSize="13sp" android:id="@+id/bt4" android:background="@color/colorAccent" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
                        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="9:00" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:textSize="13sp" android:id="@+id/bt5" android:background="@color/colorAccent" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
                        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="9:15" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:textSize="13sp" android:id="@+id/bt6" android:background="@color/colorAccent" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="75dp">
                        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="9:30" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:textSize="13sp" android:id="@+id/bt7" android:background="@color/colorAccent" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
                        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="9:45" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:textSize="13sp" android:id="@+id/bt8" android:background="@color/colorAccent" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
                        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="10:00" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:textSize="13sp" android:id="@+id/bt9" android:background="@color/colorAccent" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
                        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="10:15" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:textSize="13sp" android:id="@+id/bt10" android:background="@color/colorAccent" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
                        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="10:30" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:textSize="13sp" android:id="@+id/bt11" android:background="@color/colorAccent" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
                        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="10:45" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:textSize="13sp" android:id="@+id/bt12" android:background="@color/colorAccent" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="75dp">
                        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="11:00" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:textSize="13sp" android:id="@+id/bt13" android:background="@color/colorAccent" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
                        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="11:15" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:textSize="13sp" android:id="@+id/bt14" android:background="@color/colorAccent" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
                        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="11:30" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:textSize="13sp" android:id="@+id/bt15" android:background="@color/colorAccent" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
                        <Button android:id="@+id/bt16" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="11:45" android:textSize="13sp" android:background="@color/colorAccent" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
                        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="12:00" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:textSize="13sp" android:id="@+id/bt17" android:background="@color/colorAccent" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
                        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="12:15" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:textSize="13sp" android:id="@+id/bt18" android:background="@color/colorAccent" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="75dp">
                        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="12:30" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:textSize="13sp" android:id="@+id/bt19" android:background="@color/colorAccent" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
                        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="12:45" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:textSize="13sp" android:id="@+id/bt20" android:background="@color/colorAccent" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
                        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="13:00" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:textSize="13sp" android:id="@+id/bt21" android:background="@color/colorAccent" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
                        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="13:15" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:textSize="13sp" android:id="@+id/bt22" android:background="@color/colorAccent" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
                        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="13:30" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:textSize="13sp" android:id="@+id/bt23" android:background="@color/colorAccent" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
                        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="13:45" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:textSize="13sp" android:id="@+id/bt24" android:background="@color/colorAccent" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="75dp">
                        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="14:00" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:textSize="13sp" android:id="@+id/bt25" android:background="@color/colorAccent" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
                        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="14:15" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:textSize="13sp" android:id="@+id/bt26" android:background="@color/colorAccent" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
                        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="14:30" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:textSize="13sp" android:id="@+id/bt27" android:background="@color/colorAccent" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
                        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="14:45" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:textSize="13sp" android:id="@+id/bt28" android:background="@color/colorAccent" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
                        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="15:00" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:textSize="13sp" android:id="@+id/bt29" android:background="@color/colorAccent" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
                        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="15:15" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:textSize="13sp" android:id="@+id/bt30" android:background="@color/colorAccent" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="75dp">
                        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="15:30" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:textSize="13sp" android:id="@+id/bt31" android:background="@color/colorAccent" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
                        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="15:45" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:textSize="13sp" android:id="@+id/bt32" android:background="@color/colorAccent" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
                        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="16:00" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:textSize="13sp" android:id="@+id/b33" android:background="@color/colorAccent" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
                        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="16:15" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:textSize="13sp" android:id="@+id/bt34" android:background="@color/colorAccent" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
                        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="16:30" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:textSize="13sp" android:id="@+id/bt35" android:background="@color/colorAccent" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
                        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="16:45" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:textSize="13sp" android:id="@+id/bt36" android:background="@color/colorAccent" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="75dp">
                        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="17:00" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:textSize="13sp" android:id="@+id/bt37" android:background="@color/colorAccent" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
                        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="17:15" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:textSize="13sp" android:id="@+id/bt38" android:background="@color/colorAccent" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
                        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="17:30" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:textSize="13sp" android:id="@+id/bt39" android:background="@color/colorAccent" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
                        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="17:45" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:textSize="13sp" android:id="@+id/bt40" android:background="@color/colorAccent" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
                        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="18:00" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:textSize="13sp" android:id="@+id/bt41" android:background="@color/colorAccent" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
                        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="18:15" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:textSize="13sp" android:id="@+id/bt42" android:background="@color/colorAccent" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="75dp">
                        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="18:30" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:textSize="13sp" android:id="@+id/bt43" android:background="@color/colorAccent" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
                        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="18:45" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:textSize="13sp" android:id="@+id/bt44" android:background="@color/colorAccent" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
                        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="19:00" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:textSize="13sp" android:id="@+id/bt45" android:background="@color/colorAccent" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
                        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="19:15" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:textSize="13sp" android:id="@+id/bt46" android:background="@color/colorAccent" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
                        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="19:30" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:textSize="13sp" android:id="@+id/bt47" android:background="@color/colorAccent" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
                        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="19:45" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:textSize="13sp" android:id="@+id/bt48" android:background="@color/colorAccent" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
                    </TableRow>

                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:layout_weight="40"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="0">



            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:gravity="center|right">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/round_button"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="CANCEL"
                    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                    android:textSize="13dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:gravity="center|left">


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_okay"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/round_button"
                    android:text="OKAY"
                    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                    android:textSize="13dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

here activity code :

```
public class ViewDialog extends AppCompatActivity {


    private int buttonState = 2;


ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();


public void showDialog(Activity activity, String msg) {



   
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.time_dialog);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new 
ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

    TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txt_file_path);
    text.setText(msg);



    Button bt1 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.bt1);
    bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(buttonState % 2 == 0){
            
                
bt1.setBackgroundColor(dialog.getContext().getColor(R.color.btnclick));
                al.add(bt1.getText().toString());

            }
            else{
                
bt1.setBackgroundColor(dialog.getContext().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
                al.remove(bt1.getText().toString());

            }
            buttonState++;
        }
    });



    Button dialogBtn_cancel = (Button) 
dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);
    dialogBtn_cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
       //                    
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Cancel" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    Button dialogBtn_okay = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_okay);
    dialogBtn_okay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            
Toast.makeText(dialog.getContext(),al.get(0),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });


    dialog.show();
}
}

public class ViewDialog extends AppCompatActivity {


    private int buttonState = 2;


ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();


public void showDialog(Activity activity, String msg) {



   
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.time_dialog);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new 
ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

    TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txt_file_path);
    text.setText(msg);



    Button bt1 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.bt1);
    bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(buttonState % 1 == 0){
            
                
bt1.setBackgroundColor(dialog.getContext().getColor(R.color.btnclick));
                al.add(bt1.getText().toString());

            }
            else{
                
bt1.setBackgroundColor(dialog.getContext().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
                al.remove(bt1.getText().toString());

            }
            buttonState++;
        }
    });



    Button dialogBtn_cancel = (Button) 
dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);
    dialogBtn_cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
       //                    
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Cancel" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    Button dialogBtn_okay = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_okay);
    dialogBtn_okay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            
Toast.makeText(dialog.getContext(),al.get(0),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });


    dialog.show();
}
}
```

And also I need a variable for the selected time. please help me

## Question 1: how to make a multi-button?

## Question 2: how to make a variable for the selected time?

Comment: Can you show what kind of output you want?

Comment: can you show your any design or which type of view you want ?

Comment: @Niceumang http://imgshare.io/image/9008170f-4f05-4b36-987e-c02c9715ce09.ah6xf

Comment: @SanjayBhalanihttp://imgshare.io/image/9008170f-4f05-4b36-987e-c02c9715ce09.ah6xf

Comment: @Amin you can achieve your functionality using FLAXBOX layout and you can add dynamically buttons as you want ....."https://android.jlelse.eu/flexbox-for-android-developers-89ccbf9bfb36" check given link..

Comment: You have no other ideas? because I already created buttons and I just need one code to change the buttons background color! @Niceumang